Does measuring S21 parameter of a directional coupler include measuring S11?
I have a directional coupler RF Lambda.
Port 1: Input
Port 2: Output
Port 3: Forward Coupling
Port 4: Reverse Coupling
Port 5,6: Plugged by 50 ohm
I want to measure S21.
I have a power generator and Anritsu Power meter with power sensor.
Generator : P0 > Cable : P0 - path loss > DUT input: P1 > DUT output: P2 > Anritsu
Now my question: Do i need to measure S11 so i know the real P1 power that enters the directional coupler via Port 1?
S21dB = 10 log (P2 / P1)

This diagram shows the travelling waves incident and outgoing from a generic 2-port device:

(image source)
By definition,
$$S_{21} = \frac{b_2}{a_1}.$$
It depends only on the amplitude of the wave incident at port 1 and outgoing at port 2. The "power that gets past port 1 to enter the device" is not part of the definition.
With a perfect instrument you don't have to know \$S_{11}\$ to know \$S_{21}\$.
That said, to take account of imperfections in your instrument and resonances in the cables connecting it to your DUT, you would want to do a fully corrected measurement with a VNA, and that would include measuring \$S_{11}\$ and using it as part of the corrections for the \$S_{21}\$ measurement.
Unfortunately to do a corrected measurement you need to know the phase of the S parameters, and the equipment you have (generator and power detector) won't provide this information.

"S11 doesn't depend on "the real power entering" the device." Do you mean S21?
Anritsu MS 2036C i am using can be also used as VNA. I measured S11 with it.
What i don't understand is - is S11 usually so small that you simply leave it out from the measurement and do P2-P0, where P0 is what i set on my generator minus the path loss, and P2 is what i can measure on the power meter?
If i do i correctly and use VNA, i suppose i place the DUT in between its measuring ports and measure S21. Does the VNA automatically count in S11?

@Jan, I updated the answer to clarify. It doesn't matter if $S_{11}$ is small. By definition, $S_{21}$ depends on the incident and transmitted waves, not on the part of the incident wave that gets past the reflection at port 1.
